# what does Homotopy Tell?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is the Homotopy geometrically?And what is path-homotopy?

If two real valued functions are homotopic to each other, then what can we say about the geometry behind this? It need not be equal function but what sort of functions they are?

Comment: It involves a rubber sheet.

Comment: rubber sheet??@mvw

Comment: Sorry for the bad pun. :-) The little bit I understood means one can stretch continously $f_1$ into $f_2$ if they are homotopic, which only works if there are no holes in between. I guess it says more about the space than the functions.

Comment: Any two real-valued functions are homotopic. So homotopy tells you nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Homotopy doesn't really tell you much about the space, except $n$-connectedness and things like that. Path homotopy is nothing but homotopy of paths. As for the second question, the fundamental group of $\mathbf{R}^n$ vanishes. Therefore it is simply connected and hence any two real-valued maps are homotopic. I suggest reading Hatcher, Chapter 1.